# Name for topology defined by order

Tags: general-topology, terminology

Consider a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ that includes the following sets:
$\varnothing, \mathbb{R}, (a,\infty), [a,\infty)$
for any $a\in \mathbb{R}$.

> Does it have a name?

**Postscript.** There is [right/left order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology#Left_and_right_order_topologies) which is close, but the same.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean $(a,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,a)$? The smallest topology containing these, for each $a\in\mathbb{R}$, is the *order topology*.